# Android studio how to create virtual device with PPI?

Tags: android

I developed an Android Tablet(7 inch) application. My client testing with Twinkle i5 device.

My issues are:

**1.** I don't have device, so I should test with Emulator.

**2.** I don't know how to create Emulator with PPI Display Density.

**Specification of Twinkle i5 device:**
17.78cm (7.0”) IPS HD Full Capacitive Multi-Touch (1024*600) (PPI 170) Display.

Comment: can i know why i get negative point?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android studio it's quite easy.

1.Click on the new Hardware profile

[image]

2. Then add resolution as per your requirement

[image]

**Note:** PPI is not an independent measure. It is related to screen resolution and screen size

The formula for PPI is

```
float PPI = (float)Math.sqrt((double)(screenWidthPx*screenWidthPx + screenHeightPx*screenHeightPx))/LCD_Diagonal;
```

So in your case, if you choose a dimension of 1024 * 600 with 7-inch screen size PPI will be approx 170

i.e.

```
float PPI = (float)Math.sqrt((double)(1024*600 + 600*1024))/7 = 169.54
```

Comment: thanks for your support. I tried but I need to create PPI density, but not DPI??? here problem is display density, not resolution.